# Custom cell format displayed in US format despite using DataFormatter with UK locale

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a cell in a spreadsheet that's meant to represent a duration value.

The displayed value in Excel on Windows the 'Region' set to 'US' is  0:04:39

The displayed value in Excel on Windows the 'Region' set to 'UK' is  00:04:39

So, in US region it's using h:mm:ss and in UK, it's using hh:mm:ss

In my app that uses Apache POI (5.0.0), I want to render this value as hh:mm:ss regardless of what Locale/Region the platform is set to.

So, I've created a DataFormatter as follows:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "UK"));
```

The problem is, when I then do:

```
displayValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

The `displayValue` is still 0:04:39 / h:mm:ss

I don't want to specify a custom data format in my application, I just want it to render all cells as if the locale was set to UK on the platform.  Shouldn't `DataFormatter` be doing this?

I see that https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
doesn't contain a built-in format for hh:mm:ss - what's the best way forward here?

Comment: "Shouldn't DataFormatter be doing this?" It should but it doesn't. Only way I see is giving `DataFormatter` a hint: `...DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();... if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(java.util.Locale.UK)) df.addFormat("[$-F400]h:mm:ss\\ AM/PM", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));`.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you.  It's a bit tragic POI can't handle Locales properly

Answer (score 0):

I can override the format Excel uses for each individual type (time / duration / date) as follows:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
String dataFormatString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
if( dataFormatString.equals("h:mm") ) {
    short x = wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("hh:mm;@");
    CellStyle cf = wb.createCellStyle();
    cf.setDataFormat(x);
    cell.setCellStyle(cf);
    displayValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell).toString();
}
```

But I'll have to make sure I cover *every* format the User might choose for dates and times.  If anyone knows of a less manual way to do this, please answer.